# How to seperate the UI for the admin and the UI for the student

Tags: php, html, mysql

So basically i'm making a school system and i'm new to Php and i want to make a login page and when the student login. it will show the student's webpage. and the same thing in the admin. when the admin login it will show the webpage for the admin

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: you want one single page for login for both users or different one???

Comment: no. what i mean is after the login. i want different UI for different user

Comment: Please specify what you are thinking and have tried till now

Comment: no more like consult.

Comment: @DustinJack you have to go with Role Based LoginSystem.

Comment: i do have a design for admin and i have a design for the students' webpage. What I mean to my question is when the student logs in, the student web page will be displayed and if the user is admin the admin page will be displayed

Comment: @DustinJack So ok, but what you tried till now????

Comment: i already finish the login page and it is functional. running with phpmyAdmin. but i don't know how to start with the seperation of students' webpage and admin webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data store for user, just keep a flag is they are admin or not. Also design 2 different pages for admin and student.

Once you have the data about the logged in user you could just redirect them to the appropriate page according to the type of user

This is some sample pseudo code (won't really work)

Assume `user_type` is a function which checks the flag and tells if user is ADMIN or not, `logged_in_user` has data about your user, and `ADMIN_USER` to be a constant for identifying ADMIN users. `$adminHomeURL` is URL for admin page and `$studentHomeURL` for student page.

```
if (user_type(logged_in_user) == ADMIN_USER) {
    header('Location: ' . $adminHomeURL); // redirect use to admin page
} else {
    header('Location: ' . $studentHomeURL); // redirect use to studentpage
}
```

This should give you basic idea to go ahead with the implementation

Comment: what would you recommend me to read or watch that could   really help me with my problem

Comment: You should always exit after header location